# selecting a custom cell repeats in table

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

i am using custom cell in which there is a button which should be marked as checked upon clicking a cell.But when i click a cell it repeats in a table for eg.

cell 1

cell 2

cell 3

cell 4

cell 5

cell 6

cell 7 (repeated checked from 1)

cell 8(repeated checked from 2)

here is my code.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    WIWNotificationViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WIWNotificationViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.notifySelected=NO;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[WIWNotificationViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"WIWNotificationViewCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}




    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WIWNotificationViewCell *cell = (WIWNotificationViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (cell.notifySelected==YES)
    {
        [cell.btnNotifyClicked setSelected:NO];
        cell.notifySelected=NO;
    } else
    {
        [cell.btnNotifyClicked setSelected:YES];
        cell.notifySelected=YES;
    }
}
```

WIWNotificationViewCell is a custom cell and it contains btnNotifiedClicked to be checked.

Comment: You need to maintain the datasource for it, For ex keep an array to track of it

Comment: how ?can you please explain??

Comment: Place code of `WIWNotificationViewCell` - How you are connecting with `btnNotifyClicked`

Comment: i have taken just a outlet for btnNotifyClicked thats all in custom cell.

Answer (score -1):

When you get the cell using the reuse identifier all you are doing is setting the boolean value notifySelected.  You need to also call

```
[cell.btnNotifyClicked setSelected:NO];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath, otherwise the state of the view isn't updated until didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: It's better to do this in `prepareForReuse`